# Ticket printing via Crystal Reports (VB.NET) with Epson LX-300+

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have some problems in printing ticket by dot matrix printer.

- I have EPSON LX-300+
- I am using VB.NET 2008 and Crystal Reports
- I am using `rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 1, 1)` method to print

My problem is when I print my ticket, the alignment is perfect but the printer eject the latter size of ticket papers. It should stop after one ticket.

- ticket size Height=4,width=10
- paper setup in Crystal Reports and in printer property is envelop #10 9 1/2 * 4 1/8 in.

Answer (score 0):

note: this Method requires you to **set** a printer with a default paper size first
then access this printer when printing

This Method works with an **Epson LX-300+ ii Dot-Matrix Printer**

If you are using a Printer especially for Printing Receipts
here are the steps on how to set your printer for desired paper size

First Set up Printer to be used:
Go to **Devices and Printers**
in Printers select the Printer you are going to use and click - right click **Printer Properties**
Click **Preferences...** Button. Under **Main** Tab - Change **Document Size** to **User Defined**
a new New Window will appear. 
in Paper Size Name specify the name (i.e. OR Paper)
and change paper width and height as desired
Click **Save** then **OK**

[image]

then set your printer by Pressing right click then **set as Default Printer**

Add these line of code for your printing. You can still use parameters and datasets in printer

```
Dim c As Integer
        Dim doctoprint As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument()
        doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "EPSON L1300 Series"
        Dim rawKind As Integer
        For c = 0 To doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
            If doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(c).PaperName = "OR Receipts" Then
                rawKind = CInt(doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(c).GetType().GetField("kind", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or 

Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(doctoprint.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(c)))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Report1.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CType(rawKind, CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)
        frmPreview.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
        Report1.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 1, 1)
```